# cl.exe crashes when compiling projects from previous versions of VS

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2019

I installed VS2019, and tried to compile a project from previous version, but cl.exe crashes each time. Any ideas?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>StdAfx.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\xtr1common(50,1): error C1001:  An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\xtr1common(50,1): error C1001: (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1533)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\xtr1common(50,1): error C1001:  To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\xtr1common(50,1): error C1001: Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\xtr1common(50,1): error C1001:  Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\iosfwd(108): message :  see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<_Int>,int>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\iosfwd(136): message :  see reference to class template instantiation 'std::fpos<_Statetype>' being compiled

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: CL.exe
  Application Version:  19.21.27702.2
  Application Timestamp:    5ccaddbc
  Fault Module Name:    c1xx.dll
  Fault Module Version: 19.21.27702.2
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5ccade8e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00313256
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
```

Comment: I narrowed down the issue to the following 1 line in stdafx.h: #include <string>. What a bummer!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the #include  from stdafx.h, and eliminating compiler option /Fx.